# Can I make an ArrayList in an ArrayList (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I' would like to store user input into an ArrayList then place that ArrayList into another ArrayList. So sort of like a main category, which contains sub-categories that contain data.

Here is some of the code:

```
    ArrayList<String> mainCat = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> subCat = new ArrayList<>();
```

Could I add the "subCat" ArrayList in the "mainCat" ArrayList?

Comment: Would you want the data structure to reflect the main category -> sub category hierarchy? Perhaps a `Map<String, List<String>>` (mapping main categories into lists of sub categories) would be a better choice then.

Comment: I agree with Mic, a map is probably a better option in that case.

Comment: @MickMnemonic why map? because of collision problem and find any arraylist type string faster?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I was trying to avoid using Map or HashMaps. But I suppose that's just me being lazy.

Comment: @KickButtowski, no, because a map is ideal for building hierarchical (tree-like) models, ones like the OP's example seems to represent.

Comment: @MaxEchendu, you could get better answers if you'd add some example data and mention how you're intending to use the main and sub category lists. Your current post only has two lists that are not linked to each other in any way, making it hard to understand the actual intended usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Map` for this purpose, because it makes it easier to lookup sub categories based on the main category. If you use a `List<List<String>>`, you actually have no way to determine into which main category a given sub category belongs to. Here's an example using a `TreeMap` (which automatically keeps main categories in alphabetical order):

```
Map<String, List<String>> mainCategories = new TreeMap<>();
mainCategories.put("A", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2", "A3"));
mainCategories.put("B", Arrays.asList("B1", "B2"));
mainCategories.put("C", Arrays.asList("C1"));

System.out.println(mainCategories);
System.out.println(mainCategories.get("B"));
```

This prints out

```
{A=[A1, A2, A3], B=[B1, B2], C=[C1]}
[B1, B2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Of course! Add it just like any other `ArrayList`, except the type would be `ArrayList<String>`.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainCat = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> subCat = new ArrayList<>();
mainCat.add(subCat);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not ? But you need to make a slight change in the definition of mainCat:

```
List<List<String>> mainCat = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Because items in mainCat collection will not be String but collections.

Comment: your list should have a type don't u think? it feels very raw ?

Comment: @KickButtowski What are you talking about? His first list uses `List` as a type argument, the second one uses `String`. Both have type arguments specified

Comment: @VinceEmigh he eidted his answer

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

```
List<List<String>> mainCat = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
List<String> subCat = new ArrayList<String>();

mainCat.add(subCat);
```

Comment: if you can add good explanation, I am more than happy to vote you up